# Creating an Eigen matrix from an array with row-major order

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have an array of doubles, and I want to create a 4-by-4 matrix using the Eigen library. I also want to specify that the data is stored in row-major order. How can I do this?

I have tried the following, but it does not compile:

```
double data[16];
Eigen::Matrix4d M = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix4d>(data, 4, 4, Eigen::RowMajor);
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: What in ggael's answer is lacking? If it answers your question, you should mark it as the answer to your question. If not, post a response with details on what additional help you need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to pass a row-major matrix type to Map, e.g.:

```
Map<Matrix<double,4,4,RowMajor> > M(data);
```

then you can use M as an Eigen matrix, and the values of data will be modified, e.g.:

```
M = M.inverse();
```

If you want to copy the data to a true column-major Eigen matrix, then do:

```
Matrix4d M = Map<Matrix<double,4,4,RowMajor> >(data);
```

Of course, you can also copy to a row-major matrix by using the right type for M.

Comment: Use Dynamic and pass the sizes to the ctor: `Map<Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> >(data, nbRows, nbColumns);`

Answer (score 2):

RowMajor forms actually come in handy when using arrays to store data sometimes. Hence you can also prefer using a typedef to RowMajor type.

```
namespace Eigen{ 
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> MatrixXfRowMajor;
}
```

You can replace by float by any datatype of choice. For a 4x4 matrix then, we can simply do

```
Eigen::MatrixXfRowMajor mat;
mat.resize(4,4);
```