# How to create a row-major C array from an Eigen matrix with run-time dimensions?

Tags: eigen

The following two posts are very helpful but not quite what I need:

- [Convert Eigen Matrix to C array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443102/convert-eigen-matrix-to-c-array)
- [Creating an Eigen matrix from an array with row-major order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722899/creating-an-eigen-matrix-from-an-array-with-row-major-order)

However, I need to create a row-major C array (see [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722899/creating-an-eigen-matrix-from-an-array-with-row-major-order)) from an Eigen::MatrixXd, and I need to be able to specify the dimensions at run-time. Meaning, I'm making an interface that lets me pass an Eigen::MatrixXd to be converted along with it's dimensions and preallocated target C array.

This works but is column-major,

```
void eigen_matrixXd_to_double_array(const Eigen::MatrixXd& evector, double* destination, uint32_t nrow, uint32_t ncol)
{
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(destination,nrow,ncol) = evector;
}
```

I want something like:

```
    void eigen_matrixXd_to_double_array(const Eigen::MatrixXd& evector, double* destination, uint32_t nrow, uint32_t ncol)
{
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, nrow, ncol, Eigen::RowMajor>>(destination,nrow,ncol) = evector;
}
```

or,

```
    void eigen_matrixXd_to_double_array(const Eigen::MatrixXd& evector, double* destination, uint32_t nrow, uint32_t ncol)
{
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd<Eigen::RowMajor>>(destination,nrow,ncol) = evector;
}
```

but neither of these work...

Any suggestions? Is it possible for me to make a row-major mapping with programmatic dimensions (realizing that the user of the C interface must get the dims correct)?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ggael, that worked! Thanks for the help. For the other noobs out there, here is a slight tweak that may be helpful for copy/paste, **typedef Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::RowMajor> RowMajMat;**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close:

```
typedef Matrix<double,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> RowMajMat;
RowMajMat::Map(destination, evector.rows(), evector.cols()) = evector;
```

Here, `RowMajMat::Map` is a static method returning a `Map<RowMajMat>`, so you can also write `Map<RowMajMat>(destination, evector.rows(), evector.cols())`.