# C++ Eigen initialise dynamic matrix with raw data

Tags: c++, eigen

Suppose I have raw data, whose size I don't know at compile time, and that's why I need to store it in a dynamically sized matrix. I know I can initialise a static-sized matrix as follows:

```cpp
  std::vector<double> v {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};  // "Raw data".
  Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 2> m(v.data());
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

But is there a way of similarly initialising, or (even better) setting the data of a **dynamic** matrix? Something like the following (which doesn't compile)?

```cpp
  std::vector<double> v {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};  // "Raw data".
  Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> m(v.data(), 2, 2);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

I know from a comment in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722899/creating-an-eigen-matrix-from-an-array-with-row-major-order) that I can just use `Eigen::Map`, but as far as I understand, `Eigen::Map` doesn't *own* the memory, so I can't, for example, return it from a function. I know that I can set the matrix element-wise but that feels so dumb LOL.

Comment: If just using the `Eigen::Map` is not working in your case (because the raw memory gets destructed or overwritten), you can copy the `Map` to an `Eigen::MatrixXd` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy the raw data, assign the Map to a normal matrix.

```
std::vector<double> v {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
Eigen::MatrixXd m = Eigen::MatrixXd::Map(v.data(), 2, 2);
```

BTW: You don't need to deal with the template parameters such as `Matrix<double, 2, 2>` or `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>`: There are type definitions for common cases. Just use `Matrix2d` and `MatrixXd` in your example. The type definitions are listed [here for matrix](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html) and [here for array](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__arraytypedefs.html)